# percentage function with positive or negative numbers

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I couldn't find this question here although it seems simple.

lets say that I want to calculate the percentage of an overall distance when i know the start and end positions ie:

```
function getPercentage(startpos,endpos,currentpos)
{
     var distance = endpos-startpos;
     return (currentpos/distance)*100;
}
```

easy, but it's very late an coffee's not working what happens if the startpos or the current pos is in the negative axis i.e.

```
startpos = -734;
endpos = 65;
currentpos = -38;
```

worth noting that any position could be either in positive or negative axis at any point.

what percentage of the distance is the currentpos at.... 
Can anyone throw me a bone pleasee it's 1am :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to translate the current position as well.

```
function getPercentage(startpos, endpos, currentpos)
{
     var distance = endpos - startpos;
     var displacement = currentpos - startpos;
     return (displacement / distance) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy thing to do is to offset the positions so that startpos becomes zero:

```
endpos = endpos - startpos;
currentpos = currentpos - startpos;
var perc = currentpos/endpos*100;
```